# java.lang.Throwable: ReferenceError: event is not defined

Tags: java, dukescript

How to get clicked element text trough javascript's `event.target.value`?.

I found [this knockoutjs example](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/10229/) and want to port it to Dukescript.

Here's my try:

**HTML**

```
<div class='liveExample'>   
    <h2 class="outmodel" data-bind="value: 'A', click: myFunction">Aaaaa</h2>  
    <h2 class="outmodel" data-bind="value: 'B', click: myFunction">Bbbbb</h2>
    <h2 class="outmodel" data-bind="value: 'C', click: myFunction">Ccccc</h2>
  <hr />
  <h1 data-bind="text: say"></h1>
</div>
```

**Java:**

```
package dew.demo.ko4j;

import net.java.html.json.*;
import net.java.html.js.*;

@Model(className="Hello", properties={
  @Property(name="say", type=String.class)
})
final class HelloViaKO {

  @Function public static void myFunction(Hello model){
    model.setSay(getTextValue());
  } 

  @JavaScriptBody(args={}, body = "return event.target.value;")
  private static native String getTextValue();

  static {
    Hello model = new Hello("Hello World!");
    model.applyBindings();
  }
}
```

And you can see it on this [Fiddle](http://dew.apidesign.org/dew/#65416b30651ac41789fe), if you look at the console appears the message

`java.lang.Throwable: ReferenceError: event is not defined`

since java.awt.Event is nor present how can we reference the event like in `this.myFunction = function (data, event)`?

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
@Function public static void myFunction(Hello model, String data) {
  model.setSay(data);
}
```

as the classical [DEW sample](http://dew.apidesign.org/dew/#8848505) does.

Comment: DEW code updated but data gets turned into empty String and hence not showing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Again, this example works perfectly fine in a regular DukeScript project, but it fails in DEW. (Probably time to update DEW)